# Can't explain the reason for the invalid data structure size

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

So I was working on this Sudoku solver in Java for few days now, and while it seemed to work, after I ran it on more difficult sudokus, it just crashes sometimes.

The solver itself is not of brute force nature. It was inspired by Knuth's Algorithm X. So I have a huge matrix of 0s and 1s which the algorithm tries to completely reduce and by doing that, solve the sudoku.

The procedure kinda goes like this:

- is the matrix of 0s and 1s empty?
- if not seek the column with least ones
- pick a random row there
- for every column in that row where there is 1, remove that column
- remove that row
- repeat on the reduced matrix

Now the algorithm will always find the solution when it starts removing the right columns and rows, and will always manage to solve the easy problems. I suspect that is because the matrix it has to reduce is pretty small (matrix of possibilities to fill the blanks) and therefore there is less chance it will have to backtrack (rebuild the matrix in case wrong rows have been removed).

I have been trying for several days now, to fix the part where the matrix gets repaired since that seemed to be the problem for it to crash on hard puzzles. But after (it seemed) I fixed that, there is something impossible happening and i dont know why - the program seems to eliminate all the possibilities to solve the puzzle. Do not be scared by the amount of code, the methods before the comment line "//algorithm X" work and aren't part of the problem. Only lines below.

That should be impossible since one of the columns with the least ones will ALWAYS be part of the solution but somehow it identifies all of them as invalid...

I commented the code and put all of it into a single .java file, so you can feel free to run and try it out. There are 3 sudokus i was testing it on - "sudoku" (easy, mostly correct), "sudoku1" hard, mostly fails, "sudoku3" empty, solved always with random solution.

In the beginning of program, im also using "myFakeRandomGenerator" since I wanted random row selection to always go same path for easier debugging.

For easier understanding of how i use the HashMaps in the program, im linking the python program that inspired what i wrote so far:

http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~aassaf9/python/algorithm_x.html

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class Sudoku {

public static ArrayList<int[]> coverageMatrix = new ArrayList();
public static HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> rowsMatrix = new HashMap<>();
public static HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> columnsMatrix = new HashMap<>();
public static HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>> backupMonster = new HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>>();

public static ArrayList<Integer> invalidColumns = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static ArrayList<String> invalidRows = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> solution = new ArrayList<String>();

public static Random myFakeRandomGenerator = new Random(152);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //just rename the one you want to run into "sudoku" and off you go

    int[][] sudoku = {
        {5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0},
        {8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3},
        {4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6},
        {0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9}
    };

    int[][] sudoku2 = {
        {8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 3, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 2, 0, 0},
        {0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 7, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 8},
        {0, 0, 8, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0}
    };

    int[][] sudoku3 = {
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},};

    //we parse the input sudoku into string which is later turned into the giant complete coverage matrix
    fillTheMatrix(parseSudoku(sudoku));

    //here we just transform the giant matrix into the HashMap since it helps us with solving
    rowsMatrix = matrixToRowValuesDict(coverageMatrix);
    //we include the already given numbers of the sudoku into the solution
    solution = addGivenNumbersToSolution(rowsMatrix);
    //we generate the matrix of all possible entries for cells for algorithm X to run on
    suggestValidMissingLines(parseSudoku(sudoku));
    //since we re-generate both matrices because it was slightly altered above
    rowsMatrix = matrixToRowValuesDict(coverageMatrix);
    columnsMatrix = matrixToValueRowsDict(rowsMatrix);

    //here we run the algoritm
    solution = solve(rowsMatrix, columnsMatrix, solution);
    parseSolution(solution, rowsMatrix);
    drawSudoku(parseSolution(solution, rowsMatrix));


}

// <editor-fold desc="Sudoku parsing methods, working.">
public static ArrayList<String> addGivenNumbersToSolution(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> rowsMatrix) {

    ArrayList<String> solutions = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String key : rowsMatrix.keySet()) {
        solutions.add(key);
    }

    return solutions;

}

public static String parseSudoku(int[][] sudoku) {

    String sudokuString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < sudoku.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sudoku[i].length; j++) {
            if (sudoku[i][j] == 0) {
                sudokuString += ".";
            } else {
                sudokuString += sudoku[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return sudokuString;

}

public static void fillTheMatrix(String sudoku) {

    for (int i = 0; i < sudoku.length(); i++) {
        placeInCell(i, sudoku.substring(i, i + 1));
    }

}

public static void placeInCell(int index, String value) {

    int[] cells = new int[81];
    int[] rows = new int[81];
    int[] columns = new int[81];
    int[] boxes = new int[81];

    int[] matrixRow = new int[324];

    if (value.matches("[1-9]")) {

        //this helps us place the number in the array
        int arrayIndex = Integer.parseInt(value);

        //we fill the first quarter of the matrix row - cells
        cells[index] = 1;

        //we fill the second quarter of the matrix row - rows
        int multiplier = index / 9;
        int rowsPosition = 9 * multiplier + arrayIndex - 1;
        rows[rowsPosition] = 1;

        //we fill the third quarter of the matrix row - columns
        int colsPosition = index % 9 * 9 + (arrayIndex - 1);
        columns[colsPosition] = 1;

        //we fill the final quarter of the matrix row - boxes
        int column = index % 9;
        int row = index / 9;
        int reducedColumn = column / 3;
        int reducedRow = row / 3;
        int boxNumber = reducedColumn + (reducedRow * 3);
        int boxIndex = boxNumber * 9 + (arrayIndex - 1);
        boxes[boxIndex] = 1;

        matrixRow = mergeTheArrays(cells, rows, columns, boxes);
        coverageMatrix.add(matrixRow);

    }

}

//helper method for creating the single line of the giant matrix
public static int[] mergeTheArrays(int[] cells, int[] rows, int[] columns, int[] boxes) {

    int[] merged = new int[324];
    int mergedIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        merged[mergedIndex] = cells[i];
        mergedIndex++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        merged[mergedIndex] = rows[i];
        mergedIndex++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        merged[mergedIndex] = columns[i];
        mergedIndex++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        merged[mergedIndex] = boxes[i];
        mergedIndex++;
    }

    return merged;

}

public static String parseSolution(ArrayList<String> solution, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> rowsMatrix) {

    //our final output
    int[] numbers = new int[81];
    String sudoku = "";

    for (String key : solution) {
        int index = (rowsMatrix.get(key).get(0));
        int value = (rowsMatrix.get(key).get(2)) % 9 + 1;
        numbers[index] = value;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        sudoku += numbers[i];
    }
    return sudoku;

}

public static void drawSudoku(String sudoku) {

    System.out.print("+-------+-------+-------+\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 81; i += 9) {
        System.out.print("| ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            System.out.print(sudoku.charAt(i + j) + " ");
            if (j == 2 || j == 5 || j == 8) {
                System.out.print("| ");
            }
            if ((i == 18 || i == 45 || i == 72) && j == 8) {

                System.out.print("\n+-------+-------+-------+");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}

public static void suggestValidMissingLines(String sudoku) {

    for (int i = 0; i < sudoku.length(); i++) {
        //we find empty slots
        if (sudoku.substring(i, i + 1).equals(".")) {

            Set unitValues = new HashSet();
            unitValues.addAll(checkAllColumnPreerValues(i, sudoku));
            unitValues.addAll(checkAllRowPeerValues(i, sudoku));
            //unitValues.addAll(checkAllBoxPeerValues4x4(i, sudoku));
            //we go through values 1-9 and if that value ISN'T in any peer cell, we add the suggestion for that value
            for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
                if (!unitValues.contains(j + "")) {
                    placeInCell(i, j + "");
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

public static Set checkAllColumnPreerValues(int index, String sudoku) {
    Set<String> values = new HashSet<>();

    //here we get the column index, which in turn later enables us easier search
    int columnIndex = index % 9;

    for (int i = 0; i < sudoku.length(); i += 9) {
        if (sudoku.substring(columnIndex + i, columnIndex + i + 1).matches("[1-9]")) {
            values.add(sudoku.substring(columnIndex + i, columnIndex + i + 1));
        }
    }

    return values;

}

public static Set checkAllRowPeerValues(int index, String sudoku) {

    int rowIndex = index / 9;
    Set<String> values = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        int look = (rowIndex * 9) + i;
        if (sudoku.substring(look, look + 1).matches("[1-9]")) {
            values.add(sudoku.substring(look, look + 1));
        }
    }
    return values;

}

public static Set checkAllBoxPeerValues(int index, String sudoku) {

    int column = index % 9;
    int row = index / 9;
    int reducedCol = column / 3;
    int reducedRow = row / 3;

    int boxNumber = reducedCol + 3 * reducedRow;
    Set<String> values = new HashSet<>();

    return null;
}

//this method allows us to lookup which columns are covered by the row
public static HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> matrixToRowValuesDict(ArrayList<int[]> matrix) {

    String rowName = "row ";
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> row = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.get(i).length; j++) {
            if (matrix.get(i)[j] == 1) {
                values.add(j);
            }
        }
        row.put(rowName + i, values);
        values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
    return row;

}

//this method allows us to lookup which rows fill the column
public static HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> matrixToValueRowsDict(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> rowValuesMatrix) {

    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> valueRowsDict = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();

    for (String key : rowValuesMatrix.keySet()) {
        //iterate over every element that is stored under "key"
        for (int i = 0; i < rowValuesMatrix.get(key).size(); i++) {
            //if a value is already a key in the transformed dictionary
            int currentValue = rowValuesMatrix.get(key).get(i);
            if (valueRowsDict.keySet().contains(currentValue)) {
                //add it if it isnt added already
                if (!valueRowsDict.get(currentValue).contains(key)) {
                    valueRowsDict.get(currentValue).add(key);
                }
            } else {
                ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
                values.add(key);
                valueRowsDict.put(currentValue, values);
                values = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
        }
    }
    return valueRowsDict;

}

// </editor-fold>

//algorithm X
public static ArrayList<String> solve(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> rowColumnMatrix, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> columnRowMatrix, ArrayList<String> solution) {

    if (columnRowMatrix.isEmpty()) {
        //finished
        return solution;

    } else {
        //normal run

        //select column with least ones.

        int column = selectColumnWithLeastOnes(columnRowMatrix);

        //select a row from that column
        ArrayList<String> rowsOfSelectedColumn = columnRowMatrix.get(column);

        String row = selectRandomRow(rowsOfSelectedColumn);

        //include row in the solution
        solution.add(row);

        //reduce matrix size and check if it is still valid
        select(rowColumnMatrix, columnRowMatrix, row);

        //repeat recursively
        return solve(rowColumnMatrix, columnRowMatrix, solution);
    }

}

public static void select(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> rowColumnMatrix, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> columnRowMatrix, String selectedRow) {

    //here we collect all the rows that we will remove
    Set<String> encounters = new HashSet<>();

    //deep copy
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> testCopy = new HashMap(columnRowMatrix);
    for (Integer key : columnRowMatrix.keySet()) {
        ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String value : columnRowMatrix.get(key)) {
            tmp.add(value);
        }
        testCopy.put(key, tmp);
    }
    backupMonster.put(selectedRow, testCopy);

    //this will tell us which columns to remove
    ArrayList<Integer> columnsToRemove = rowColumnMatrix.get(selectedRow);

    //we fill the set with all the rows that we will have to remove from columns
    for (Integer column : rowColumnMatrix.get(selectedRow)) {
        for (String subRow : columnRowMatrix.get(column)) {

            encounters.add(subRow);
        }
    }

    //we then remove the row letters from column matrix
    for (String encouter : encounters) {
        ArrayList<Integer> columns = rowColumnMatrix.get(encouter);
        //createbackup
        for (Integer columnd : columns) {
            columnRowMatrix.get(columnd).remove(encouter);
        }
    }

    //finally, we remove the rows from the matrix as well.
    for (Integer rowToRemove : columnsToRemove) {
        columnRowMatrix.remove(rowToRemove);
    }

    //after the matrix has been reduced, we check if it's still valid, and if not we rebuild and rerun the solve() on repaired one.
    if (!areColsValid(columnRowMatrix)) {
        invalidRows.add(selectedRow);
        solution.remove(selectedRow);
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> testRestore = backupMonster.get(selectedRow);
        for (Integer key : testRestore.keySet()) {
            ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String value : testRestore.get(key)) {
                tmp.add(value);
            }
            columnRowMatrix.put(key, tmp);
        }

    }

}
//this method checks if the columnsMatrix is still valid state (there should be NO keys with empty values - 1 key has to have AT LEAST 1 value)
public static boolean areColsValid(HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> columnsMatrix) {

    for (Integer key : columnsMatrix.keySet()) {
        if (columnsMatrix.get(key).isEmpty()) {

            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}

public static Integer selectColumnWithLeastOnes(HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> columnRowMatrix) {

    int leastElements = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    ArrayList<Integer> possibleCandidates = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //first we figure out lowest 1 amount
    for (Integer column : columnRowMatrix.keySet()) {
        if (columnRowMatrix.get(column).size() < leastElements) {
            leastElements = columnRowMatrix.get(column).size();
        }
    }

    //we add the columns with that amount of ones
    for (Integer column : columnRowMatrix.keySet()) {
        int counter = 0;
        if (columnRowMatrix.get(column).size() == leastElements) {
            //we check if all the rows yield wrong result, then we dont include this column
            for(String candidateRow : columnRowMatrix.get(column))
            {
                if (invalidRows.contains(candidateRow)) {
                    counter+=1;
                }
                if (counter==columnRowMatrix.get(column).size()) {
                    invalidColumns.add(column);
                }
            }

            if (!invalidColumns.contains(column)) {
                possibleCandidates.add(column);
            }
        }
    }

    //we randomly pick a column BUT take care not to pick the one that gives unsolveable case
    //int random = new Random().nextInt(possibleCandidates.size());
    int random = myFakeRandomGenerator.nextInt(possibleCandidates.size());
    //we generate new random until we have a valid candidate
    while (invalidColumns.contains(possibleCandidates.get(random))) {
        //random = new Random().nextInt(possibleCandidates.size());
        random = myFakeRandomGenerator.nextInt(possibleCandidates.size());

    }

    return possibleCandidates.get(random);
}

public static String selectRandomRow(ArrayList<String> rowsFromSelectedCol) {
    //int random = new Random().nextInt(rowsFromSelectedCol.size());
    int random = myFakeRandomGenerator.nextInt(rowsFromSelectedCol.size());

    while (invalidRows.contains(rowsFromSelectedCol.get(random))) {
        //random = new Random().nextInt(rowsFromSelectedCol.size());
          random = myFakeRandomGenerator.nextInt(rowsFromSelectedCol.size());
    }

    return rowsFromSelectedCol.get(random);
}

//we identify column as invalid if all of it's rows are in the invalidRows arraylist
public static boolean isColumnValid(ArrayList<String> invalidRows, int column){
    ArrayList<String> rowsToCheck = columnsMatrix.get(column);
    int counter = rowsToCheck.size();
    for(String entry : rowsToCheck){
        if (invalidRows.contains(entry)) {
            counter+=1;
        }
    }
    if (counter == rowsToCheck.size()) {
        return false;
    }
return true;
}

}
```

Comment: "it just crashes sometimes" .. can you be a bit more specific about this?

Comment: "Do not be scared by the amount of code, the methods before the comment line "//algorithm X" work and aren't part of the problem." Then they shouldn't be in the question. Please produce a [mcve] - I suspect that while doing the work to produce it, you may find the issue.

Comment: where does it crash, post the `stackTrace`,

Comment: Testing with `sudoku2` generates `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive` on a call to `Random.nextInt(possibleCandidates.size())`. Suggest you fix that first.